# crash when accessing attributes at index 0 NSAttributedString iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I need to get an array of all attributes and then to get the attribute at index 0. My solution is unsafe but didn't found a way to check if an instance of `NSAttributedString` as at least one attribute.

Is there a way to get the array of attributes withing `NSAttributedString` or to check whether it has at least one?

Comment: You can enumerate the attributes using `enumerateAttributes`. You cannot simply list attributes.

Comment: What's your code? It's unclear what you are doing. How do you get all the attributes?